# Simpler way with datetime time deltas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

and thanks in advance!  I've got a function I wrote that generates and appends a url to a list in the form of "http://www.examplesite.com/'year' + '-' + 'month'", appending a string format of the given year for each month.  The function works just fine for what I'm trying to do, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to go about it using Python 3's datetime module, possibly working with time deltas.

```
    source = 'https://www.examplesite.com/'
    year = 2017
    month = ['12', '11', '10', '09', '08', '07', '06', '05', '04', '03', '02', '01']

    while year >= 1989:
        for entry in month:
            page = source + str(year) + '-'  entry
            pageRepository.append(page)
        year -= 1
```

Comment: I am not aware with your use of year and month but in python you can use epoch time which is more better way to do your stuff.

Comment: This seems straightforward enough, I would just ditch the `while` loop for a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13)
>>> import datetime
>>> for year in range(1989, datetime.datetime.utcnow().year + 1):
...     for month in range(1, 13):
...             print('{:%Y-%m}'.format(datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)))
...
1989-01
1989-02
1989-03
1989-04
1989-05
...
2017-11
2017-12
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to subtract 1 to decrease the year even using datetime object as:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> print date.today().year - 1
```

result is 2016.  I think the way you process year is good enough.

just want to simplify the month, using range() other than hard coded month list:

```
>>> for month in range(12,0,-1):
...     str(month).zfill(2)
...
'12'
'11'
'10'
'09'
'08'
'07'
'06'
'05'
'04'
'03'
'02'
'01'
```

**str.zfill(width):**

> Return a copy of the string left filled with ASCII '0' digits to make a string of length width.